# Grails: can I modify existing HTTP headers in an uncommitted response?

Tags: servlets, grails, http-headers

In my Grails app I'd like to make a custom request filter that looks for an existing 'Location' redirect header and modifies it if the response has not yet been committed.

I don't see a method on the response object to even READ the existing headers, much less overwrite them.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by creating a wrapper (extending `HttpServletResponseWrapper`) and overrideing the `setHeader(..)` method. There you can replace the header right before it is added to the response.

The wrapper is utilized by creating it in a filter:

```
 chain.doFilter(request, new ResponseWrapper(response))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now I'm trying to figure out how to set up a ResponseWrapper from a Grails request filter.  Haven't found an answer on the web so I opened up a new StackOverflow question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763683/grails-how-do-i-set-up-a-response-wrapper-in-a-grails-filter)

Comment: I saw it, but to be honest, I don't know. I checked the docs, and there's nothing there. On tuesday I may check our codebase to see if we are wrapping anything via grails filters, but I think we are doing it through a regular filter in web.xml.