# Grails: how do I set up a response wrapper in a Grails filter?

Tags: grails, servlet-filters

I want to modify the response content of specific Grails requests.  How do I configure a ResponseWrapper in a request filter?

I had hoped it would be the following, but the response is a read-only property:

```
class MyFilters {
    def filters = {
        wrapFoo(controller:'foo', action:'bar') {
            before = {
                response = new MyResponseWrapper(response)
            }
        [...]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't - Grails filters are wrappers for Spring HandlerInterceptors and are invoked further up the processing chain than servlet filters. If you want to wrap the response you need to use a real servlet filter.

Create the class in src/java or src/groovy that implements `javax.servlet.Filter` and register it in web.xml like you would in a non-Grails application. To get access to web.xml run `grails install-templates` and edit the file in src/templates/war